# How to get hard drive unique serial number in C#

Tags: c#

I develop an activation for a system. to generate request code, I used HDD ID, Bios ID and Processor ID. I used following code to get hard disk ID.

```
private string getHardDiskID()
{
     string hddID = null;
     ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
     ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
     foreach (ManagementObject strt in moc)
     {
         hddID += Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
     }
     return hddID.Trim().ToString();
}
```

But if I plug a removable disk, That ID value is changed. How to get the UNIQUE Serial Number of the hard drive...?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The final `.ToString()` in the return is useless.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16941/Get-Physical-HDD-Serial-Number-without-WMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try from this [source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6077/How-to-Retrieve-the-REAL-Hard-Drive-Serial-Number):

As said in the source, *a better solution is to get the Hard Drive Serial Number given by the Manufacturer. This value won't change even if you format your Hard Drive.*

```
 searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

   int i = 0;
   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
    // get the hard drive from collection
    // using index
    HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];

    // get the hardware serial no.
    if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
     hd.SerialNo = "None";
    else
     hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    ++i;
   }
```

Comment: what is the reference of HardDrive

Comment: Is there another way to get the serial number?

Answer (score 2):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;

searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
        string serial_number="";

        foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
        {

             serial_number = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();


        }

        MessageBox.Show(serial_number);
```

Comment: You should explain what the code you've provided does, how it helps resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code to get HDD Serial

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

 objSearcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

   int i = 0;

   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in objSearcher.Get())
   {

    // get the hard drive from collection
    // using index
    HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];

    // get the hardware serial no.
    if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)

     hd.SerialNo = "None";

    else

     hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    ++i;

   }
```

> Also You can type "wbemtest" in windows run. WBEMTEST is tool which
>   helps in running WQL queries.

Comment: I got above code. But I have a doubt. Is this code UNIQUE for hard drive..? It returns 14 characters string.

Comment: @Jayashan [Is a hard drive's serial number globally unique?](http://serverfault.com/questions/300448/is-a-hard-drives-serial-number-globally-unique)